# Integrating $\frac1{2\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(1+erf(\frac{z-\mu_i}{\sigma_i\sqrt2}))\exp( -\frac12(\frac{z-\mu}\sigma)^2)dz$

Tags: probability, integration

I am interested in the integral of
$$\frac{1}{2\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( 1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{z-\mu_i}{\sigma_i\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)dz$$

where $\operatorname{erf}$ is the error function defined as the CDF of the standard normal (up to a constant).

In this case $\sigma, \mu, \mu_i, \sigma_i$ are constants.

I truly have no clue how to even start something like this. Is Mathematica even capable of this type of integral?

For those curious, this is evaluated when considering $Pr(f_i \leq f \leq f_j)$ where $f_j, f_i, f$ follow a normal distribution with different parameters. The full integral is

$$\frac{1}{2\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( 1+erf\left(\frac{z-\mu_i}{\sigma_i\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)dz \\
  - \frac{1}{4 \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( 1+erf \left(\frac{z-\mu_i}{\sigma_i \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\left(1+erf\left(\frac{z-\mu_j}{\sigma_j \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)dz$$

But I thought that might be inappropriate ;)

Comment: You are looking for the closed-form of $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-(x-x_0)^2}\operatorname{erf}x\,dx$, which might not exist generally.

Comment: @Julian This is a gentle reminder to consider accepting an answer if your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Integral of one error function and Gaussian*

Mathematica does not evaluate the integral. Surprisingly, there is an [exact result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Integral_of_error_function_with_Gaussian_density_function). By changing variables, $z-\mu=x$, your integral of $\operatorname{erf} \times \text{Gaussian}$ may be written as

$$
I(b)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \operatorname{erf}(ax+b) \exp \left(-cx^2 \right)
$$

Since $\partial_t \operatorname{erf}(t)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t^2}$, differentiating with respect to $b$ produces

$$
\partial_b I(b)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left( -(ax+b)^2-cx^2 \right)
$$

This is just a Gaussian integral over $x$, the result is

$$
\partial_b I(b)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+c}} \exp \left( -\frac{b^2 c}{a^2 +c} \right)
$$

Now we integrate to recover $I(b)$

$$
I(b)-I(0)=\int\limits_0^b \ dt \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+c}} \exp \left( - t^2\frac{ c}{a^2 +c} \right)
$$

$I(0)=\int dx \ ( \text{odd function})=0$, and the integral on the right is simply the definition of $\operatorname{erf}$, so we have

$$
I(b)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}} \operatorname{erf} \left( b \sqrt{\frac{c}{a^2+c}} \right) 
$$

$$
\tag*{$\blacksquare$}
$$

*Integral of two error functions and Gaussian*

We may use a similar method to find that

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \operatorname{erf}(a_1 x) \operatorname{erf}(a_2 x) e^{-cx^2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{c\pi}} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{a_1 a_2}{ \sqrt{c(a_1^2+a_2^2+c)}} \right)
$$

However, once we introduce $b\neq 0$, we meet the more complicated integral in an intermediate step

$$
\int\limits_0^b dt \ \operatorname{erf}(\alpha t + \beta) e^{-\gamma t^2}
$$

Update! Using the [result from this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087504/generalized-owens-t-function?noredirect=1&lq=1), we can make progress. Let

$$
J(\beta)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \operatorname{erfc}(\alpha x+\beta) \operatorname{erf}(a x+b) \exp \left(-cx^2 \right)
$$

Then $J(\infty)=0$. Differentiating

$$
\partial_{\beta} J(\beta)=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}  \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \  \operatorname{erf}(a x+b) \exp \left(-cx^2 - (\alpha x +\beta)^2 \right) 
$$

Which we can evaluate using our first result

$$
\partial_{\beta} J(\beta)=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c+\alpha^2}} \operatorname{erf}\left( \left(b-\frac{a \alpha \beta}{c+\alpha^2} \right) \sqrt{\frac{c+\alpha^2}{c+\alpha^2+a^2}} \right) \exp \left( -\beta^2 \left( 1+\frac{\alpha^2}{c+\alpha^2}\right) \right)
$$

With $\Lambda=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c+\alpha^2}}$, $A=-\frac{a \alpha }{c+\alpha^2}  \sqrt{\frac{c+\alpha^2}{c+\alpha^2+a^2}}$, $B=b\sqrt{\frac{c+\alpha^2}{c+\alpha^2+a^2}}$, and $C=\left( 1-\frac{\alpha^2}{c+\alpha^2}\right)$. Now we integrate

$$
J(\infty)-J(\beta)=-\int\limits_\beta^\infty \ dt \Lambda \operatorname{erf}(At+B)e^{-Ct^2}
$$

$$
J(\beta)=\int\limits_\beta^\infty dt \ \Lambda \operatorname{erf}(At+B)e^{-Ct^2}= \frac{\Lambda}{\sqrt{2C}}  \int\limits_{\sqrt{2C}\beta}^\infty du \ \operatorname{erf}(Au/\sqrt{2C}+B)e^{-u^2/2}
$$

Which may be written in terms of the 'Generalized Owen-T' function

$$
J(\beta)=\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi} \Lambda}{\sqrt{C}}T\left( \sqrt{2C}\beta, A/\sqrt{C},\sqrt{2}B\right)
$$

Using [identity ii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087504/generalized-owens-t-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) we have

$$
J(\beta)=\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi} \Lambda}{\sqrt{C}} \left[ \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \tan^{-1}(A/\sqrt{C})  -\tan^{-1}(A/\sqrt{C} + B/\beta\sqrt{C}) \\ -\tan^{-1}(B^{-1}(\beta \sqrt{C} +AB/\sqrt{C} + A^2 \beta /\sqrt{C} )) \right)  +\frac{1}{4} \operatorname{erf}(B (1+A^2/C)^{-1/2}) \\ +T(\beta \sqrt{2C},(A\beta^{-1}+B)/\beta \sqrt{C})+T(\sqrt{2}B (1+A^2/C)^{-1/2}, B^{-1}(\beta \sqrt{C} +AB/\sqrt{C} + A^2 \beta /\sqrt{C}  ) \right]
$$

Where $T$ is the [Owen T function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function). I've checked it numerically, I hope there are no typos here.

*Approximate integral of two or more error functions with Gaussian*

We can approximate the integral using Laplace's method. I'll demonstrate with two error functions, but in principle you could have more. Let

$$
I(c)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \operatorname{erf}(a_1 x+ b_1) \operatorname{erf}(a_2 x+ b_2) e^{-cx^2}
$$

Expand the product of $\operatorname{erf}$s around the Gaussian peak: $x=0$

$$
\operatorname{erf}(a_1 x+ b_1) \operatorname{erf}(a_2 x+ b_2) = \operatorname{erf}( b_1) \operatorname{erf}( b_2) + x \left( \text{junk} \right)  + x^2 \frac{2 e^{-b_1^2-b_2^2}}{\pi} \left( 2 a_1 a_2 -a_2^2 b_2 e^{b_1^2} \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}(b_1) - a_1^2b_1 e^{b_2^2} \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}(b_2) \right) + \mathcal{O}(x^3) 
$$

Term by term integration produces the asymptotic series. The $(\text{junk})$ and all $x^{\text{odd}}$ terms integrate to zero. Noting that

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ x^{2n} e^{-cx^2} = c^{-n-1/2} \Gamma(n+1/2)
$$

For *fixed* $a_i, \ b_i$ we have

$$
I(c) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}}  \operatorname{erf}( b_1) \operatorname{erf}( b_2) \\ +\frac{1}{c^{3/2}}  \frac{ e^{-b_1^2-b_2^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left( 2 a_1 a_2 -a_2^2 b_2 e^{b_1^2} \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}(b_1) - a_1^2b_1 e^{b_2^2} \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}(b_2) \right) \ \ , \ \ c \to \infty 
$$

Which is the two term approximation.

Comment: Holy (explicative)! I am amazed :). Would a similar technique apply for the second term, where we have as the integrand $\text{erf}(ax+b)\text{erf}(cx+d)\exp(-gx^2)$ where $a,b,c,d,g$ are constants?

Comment: Great answer @Sal! Many thanks!

Comment: @drandran12 Thank you, glad you found it helpful