# integral of $e^{-x^2} N(ax+b)$

Tags: integration, statistics, stochastic-processes

for a stochastic model
\begin{equation}
dS_{t} = rS_{t}dt + \sigma_1 dW_{1t} + \sigma_2dW_{2t}\\
dW_{1t} dW_{2t} = 0
\end{equation}
under the risk neutral measure, I need to calculate the value of a call option,
\begin{equation}
C_{t} = E\big( (S_{T} - K)_{+}\big| F_t\big)
\end{equation}
where $T$ is the maturity and $K$ is a s trike of the call option.

When calcultating this, I encountered an integral that is hard for me to solve as below

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}N(ax + b) dx
\end{equation}
where $N(x)$ is the cumulative normal distribution function.

Is there any way to calculate this?

Not only a perfect solution but also a hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You can first note that the sum of Wiener processes is a Wiener process. Hence this is a special case of the Vasicek model. You can find the derivations for call option pricing under this model online.

Comment: This is essentially an integral of an error function and Gaussian. There is a solution eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039)