# Gaussian Integrals of Powers of Complementary Error Function

Tags: gaussian-integral, error-function

Can anyone help me with the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt \frac{\exp\left\{-t^2/2\right\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}\left\{\frac{a-bt}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}\right)^n,
$$
where erfc is the complementary error function, $n$ is any positive integer, $a$ & $b$ can be any real number (the special case where $b =1$ is trivial...)? Many thanks in advance

Comment: The exact answer for $n=1$ and $n=2$, as well as an approximate solution for arbitrary $n$, is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need to know all the exact results of the same expression with arbitrary integer $n>0$. In fact, what I really want to calculate is $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt \frac{\exp\left\{-t^2/2\right\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \log\left\{c + \frac{d}{2} \text{erfc}\left\{\frac{a-bt}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}\right\},$$ where for now $c$ & $d$ could be approximately $0$ & $1$, but $b \not=1$ as this is a trivial case.