# Gaussian bigger than other gaussians

Tags: probability-theory, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, gaussian-integral

Let $N_1, N_2, N_3$ be three independent Gaussian random variables. Is there a closed form for
$$
\mathbf P \big[\{N_1 \ge N_2\} \cap \{ N_1 \ge N_3\}\big]=\int_{\mathbb R} \Phi_2(y)\Phi_3(y)  p_1(y)\,dy\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,?$$
Here $p_n$ and $\Phi_n$ are the density and cdf of $N_n$.

If not, what is likely to be the fastest way to numerically evaluate this number (possibly considering the general case $\mathbf P [\cap_{n=2}^N \{ N_1 \ge N_n\}]$)?

Comment: It is  evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039)

Comment: For numerical evaluation, if $N$ is large, a Monte Carlo simulation might be a nice approach....

Comment: What would you say it's the best approach for $N$ between 10 and 20? (Say reaching 5 digits precision as fast as possible)