# How to solve integral involving normal distribution and error function and x

Tags: integration

I

$$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^S _{-\infty} x \cdot\exp\left(\frac{-{\left(x-\mu \right)}^{2}}{2\sigma }\right)\cdot \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{A(x-\mu )}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: After rescaling, we have $I=\int dx \  x \exp(-(x-\mu)^2)\operatorname{erf}(a(x-\mu)))$. Let $y=x-\mu$, then we have $I=J+K$, where $J=\int dy \ e^{-y^2}\operatorname{erf}(ay)$, the general case is solved here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039), but in this case $J=0$ as the integrand is odd. Then $I=K(a)=\int dy \ y e^{-y^2}\operatorname{erf}(ay)$. By taking the $a$ derivative then doing the $y$ integral: $K'(a)=(1+a^2)^{-3/2}$, this may be integrated wrt $a$ to find $K(a)=I=a(1+a^2)^{-1/2}$

Comment: In that case, the result is not likely to be pretty (also, you should update your question to include the limits!). Using the expression for $J(\infty)-J(\beta)$ in the linked post we may find $\int^s dy e^{-y^2}\operatorname{erf}(ay)$, then to find the integral with an extra $y$ in the integrand, introduce an exponential: $\int^s dy \ e^{-y^2}e^{ky}\operatorname{erf}(ay)$, again this may be evaluated with the help of $J(\beta)$. Then differentiate wrt $k$ and set $k=0$.

Comment: I suspect the *answer* would be too long to fit in a comment, judging by the mess that comes from *one* evaluation of $J(\beta)$. I'll try and post a more explicit 'recipe' soon.

Comment: this is a gentle reminder to [accept](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) an answer if your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will calculate

$$
I(a,b,c):=\int\limits_{-\infty}^c dx \ x e^{-(x-a)^2} \operatorname{erf}(b(x-a))
$$

Which is equivalent to your integral upon rescaling $x$. We will make use of the following results from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039)

$$
J(A,B,C,D)=\int\limits_D^\infty dx \ e^{-Cx^2} \operatorname{erf}(Ax+B)=2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{C}} \ T(D\sqrt{2C},A/\sqrt{C},B\sqrt{2})
$$

Where $T$ is the 'generalized Owen T function' defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087504/generalized-owens-t-function?noredirect=1&lq=1). $J$ may be expressed in terms of elementary functions and the 'regular' [Owen T function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function). When $D=-\infty$ we have

$$
J(A,B,C,-\infty)=
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{C}}\operatorname{erf} \left(B \sqrt{\frac{C}{A^2+C}}\right)
$$

Now define $K$ as

$$
K(A,B,C,D):=J(A,B,C,-\infty) \ - \ J(A,B,C,D)
$$

First let $x-a=y$

$$ \tag{*}
I(a,b,c)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c-a} dy \ ye^{-y^2} \operatorname{erf}(by) +a\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c-a} dy \ e^{-y^2} \operatorname{erf}(by)
$$

The second integral on the right is already in the form of $K$. We need to evaluate the first. Let

$$
L(b,c,\alpha):=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c} dy \ e^{\alpha y}e^{-y^2} \operatorname{erf}(by)
$$

So that the first integral on the right in (*) is given by $\partial_\alpha L(b,c-a,0)$. Complete the square in the exponents to find

$$
L(b,c,\alpha)=e^{\alpha^2/4}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c} dy \ e^{-(y-\alpha/2)^2} \operatorname{erf}(by)=e^{\alpha^2/4}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c-\alpha/2} dt \ e^{-t^2} \operatorname{erf}(bt+\alpha b/2)
$$

The integral on the right is now again in terms of $K$

$$
L(b,c,\alpha)=e^{\alpha^2/4} K(b,\alpha b/2,1,c-\alpha/2)
$$

Putting it all together we have

$$
I(a,b,c)=\partial_\alpha L(b,c-a,\alpha) \bigg|_{\alpha=0} + a K(b,0,1,c-a)
$$

I hope they're no typos here! In any case, this is the strategy mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much!