# $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}e^{-\left(x+c\right)^{2}}dx$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I know how to solve $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}e^{-x^{2}}dx$ using upper incomplete gamma function (we can assum that
$\left|b\right|>\left|a\right|$) $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}e^{-x^{2}}dx=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{2x}{2x^{2}}e^{-x^{2}}dx\stackrel{\begin{array}{c}
t=x^{2}\\
dt=2xdx
\end{array}}{=}\int_{a^{2}}^{b^{2}}\frac{1}{2t}e^{-t}dt=\frac{1}{2}\left[\Gamma\left(0,a^{2}\right)-\Gamma\left(0,b^{2}\right)\right]$$
there is something that I can do when I have some phase in the exponent:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}e^{-\left(x+c\right)^{2}}dx=?$$
Even an evaluation will help,

thanks!

Comment: There really seems to be no closed form for the phased version, but there may be a series evaluation or a version in terms of a more general function.

Comment: There may be a closed form. It will not be neat though. Let $I(\alpha)=\int_a^b dx \ e^{-(x+c)^2+\alpha x}$, which may be evaluated in terms of the error function. The requested integral is $\int d\alpha \ I(\alpha) $, and *this* integral is in the form of Gaussian times error function which you may find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183039/how-to-solve-integral-involving-normal-distribution-and-error-function-and-x/4188543#4188543) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039)

Comment: @Sal Maybe you can post a solution or a start of a solution as an answer?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I will if I make any progress. My first attempt resulted in a divergent integral though...