# An complicated integral involving Erfi function

Tags: definite-integrals, gaussian-integral, error-function, approximate-integration

Sir,
While, studying the diffraction of the Gaussian beam through apertures, I have faced the following integral *(as an expression of diffracted field)*,
$$I= \int_0^R \exp(-\alpha r^2+i\beta r)\bigg[\operatorname{erfi}(A+i B r)-\operatorname{erfi}(A-i B r)\bigg] \,dr$$
where, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $A$ and $B$ are constants.

and I am trying to find out the closed form answer of this integral, from which further analysis can be made by varying/ adjusting the beam parameters following the experimental set up.

Sir, would you kindly suggest me how I can get the closed form answer of this integral or any relevant references from where I can get some help.

Thanking you....

Comment: @Gary...Thanks....

Comment: Complete the square in the exponent. Split the integral. Use $\operatorname{Erfi}(z)=-i\operatorname{Erf}(iz)$. The resulting integral of error function times Gaussian is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183039/how-to-solve-integral-involving-normal-distribution-and-error-function-and-x/4188543#4188543)

Comment: @Sal... Sir, thanks for your kind response. But I have a doubt that in the link, you have shared, the limit of the integral goes from (- Infinity) to a finite number, where in my case, the limits are finite. Further, I have gone through the solution shown here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039) but at the final stage, while doing the partial integration I got back the initial expression again.

Comment: Okay, so $J(\beta)=\int\limits_\beta^\infty \dots$ is the integral in your linked post. The expression for $J$ is in that post too: it's the lengthy one involving $\tan^{-1}$ and $T$, the Owen-T function. Once you have that, you can find the integral with other limits since $\int\limits_a^b=\int\limits_a^\infty-\int\limits_b^\infty$

Comment: @ Sal......Sir, Thanks once again...I am trying to solve following your suggestion. If I get stuck with a particular step, I shall disturb you again....

Comment: @Sal.......Sir, I am still facing the trouble at the last stage where the constant C [appears in addition to the Owen T function] is to be determined [after equating partial derivative at both sides]. While trying to determine C, I have got back again the integration similar to the initial expression. What can I do now?

Comment: In the link the constant $C$ is also given in terms of $\alpha$ and $c$

Comment: @Sal....Sir, thank you...finally I got it and the Answer is in terms of Generalized Owen T Function...But I think the plot of Generalized Owen T function is not possible in Mathematica , it should be done by integrate  numerically..On the other hand, the plot of Owen T function i.e. T(x,a) is available in Mathematica.

Comment: In the link the result is also given in terms of the regular Owen T function and $\tan^{-1}$

Comment: @Sal.....Sir, got it...it is there in the link...Is there any book or any reference where this "Generalized Owen T function" has been dealt with. I have searched through Google, but it only shows the derivation in Mathematics stack exchange.