# Tips on integral of exponential and error function

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, special-functions, error-function

In my work I've come across an integral on the form
$$
\int\limits_{x_0}^\infty \exp\left[-a x^2 \right] \text{erf} \left[b x + c \right] \ \mathrm{d}x \ , \qquad a > 0, \quad b, c \in \mathbb{R}
$$
which I cannot for the life of me figure out. Neither Mathematica nor Maple could help me find a closed-form solution with the given limits. I've found solutions for $x_0 = 0$ and $x_0 = -\infty$, but no general solution for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. I suspect there's no analytic solution, but I thought I'd ask here as a last resort.

With variable substitution and integration by parts, I end up juggling between different versions of
$$
\int\limits_{x_0}^\infty x^{2m} \exp\left[-x^2 \right] \text{erf} \left[\beta x + \gamma \right] \ \mathrm{d}x \ , \qquad m \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
but I feel no closer to the solution. I've also tried the trick of differentation outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78635/1105701), but I end up with the same problem.

Korotkov's *Integrals Related to the Error Function* gives solutions for integrands with a factor of $x^{2m + 1}$, which leads me to suspect that there isn't any solution for $x^{2m}$.

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is the $m$th derivative wrt $a$ of $\int e^{-ax^2}\operatorname{erf}(\beta x+\gamma)$. That integral evaluates to a sum of OwenT and trig functions, as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183039/how-to-solve-integral-involving-normal-distribution-and-error-function-and-x/4188543#4188543)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve integral involving normal distribution and error function and x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183039/how-to-solve-integral-involving-normal-distribution-and-error-function-and-x)

Comment: @Sal That's it! Thank you so much, the response you linked is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know about Owen's T-function, but I see it's used to describe situations related to the one that gave me the integral above. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @asbjoree No problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the related integral
$$
G(a)=\int\limits_{x_0}^\infty dx \ e^{-ax^2}\operatorname{erf}(\alpha x+\gamma)
$$

So that your integral is $\left(-\frac{d}{da}\right)^m G(1)$. It turns out $G(a)$ evaluates to a sum of trig and OwenT functions, as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039) and used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183039/how-to-solve-integral-involving-normal-distribution-and-error-function-and-x/4188543#4188543) to evaluate a similar integral.